# How to display data giving by user in other component in React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hey so I'm working on a project react js about the rerservation, in **DemandeVisite.js** the user should fill the form and when he confirm it should display in other component **Reservation.js** as cards.

My problem is when I call **Reservation.js** in **DemandeVisite.js** to pass the props the cards display under the form in **DemandeVisite.js** and I don't know how i can pass props to **Reservation.js** without letting it display in My **DeamndeVisite.js**.

`DemandeVisite.js`

```
import { useRef, useState } from "react";
import Reservation from "../reservation/Reservation";
import "./DemandeVisite.css"

function DemandeVisite() {
  const dateRef = useRef();
  const debutRef = useRef();
  const finRef = useRef();
  const detailRef = useRef();
  

  const [cards, setCards] = useState([]);

  const confirm = () => {
    let c = {
      dateDebut: dateRef.current.value,
      heureDebut: debutRef.current.value,
      heureFin: finRef.current.value,
      detail: detailRef.current.value
    };
    var p = [...cards, c];
    setCards(p);

    
    
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="page">
        <div className="cover3">
          <label>Date de visite :</label>
          <input type="date" ref={dateRef} />
          <label>Heure debut :</label>
          <input type="time" ref={debutRef} />
          <label>Heure fin :</label>
          <input type="time" ref={finRef} />
          <label>Pourquoi vous voulez nous visiter ?</label>
          <textarea ref={detailRef} />
          <div className="confirm-btn" onClick={confirm}>
            Confirmé
          </div>
        </div>
      </div> 
      <Reservation card={cards}/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default DemandeVisite;
```

`Reservation.js`

```
import "./Reservation.css";

function Reservation(props) {

  const card = props.card;


  return (

    <div>
      <section>
        <div className="container">
          <h1>Votre reservation</h1>
          <div className="cards">
            {card && card.map((card) => {
              return (
                <div className="card" key={card.dateDebut}>
                  <h1>{card.dateDebut}</h1>
                  <br />
                  <p>
                    Heure de debut :{card.heureDebut} et heure de fin :{" "}
                    {card.heureFin}
                  </p>
                  <br />
                  <p>En cours de validation </p>
                  <br />
                  <div className="btn">
                    <button className="btn1">Voir plus</button>
                    <button className="btn2">Annuler</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              );
            })}
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
  );
}
export default Reservation;
```

Comment: You have already passed the `card` prop to `Reservation` component

Comment: I know I did but the cards display on the same page as the form which it shouldn't

Comment: so you need to make routes and navigate user to card details page when user clicks on button to confirm the card

Comment: I did that ` <Link to="./Reservation" className="confirm-btn" onClick={confirm}>Confirmé</Link> ` but cards don't display in Reservation.js I don't know why

Comment: You need to store cards in localstorage or redux to get displayed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i hear you well you want your submitted data displayed on another page right ?
You need to implement routing, i recommend [React Router](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/overview). Then implement useNavigate with data you want to pass.

Assuming you have path `/home/:date/:age` set up already.

```
import {useNavigate} from 'react-router-dom'
function () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate()

return(
           <a
             onClick={() => {
              navigate(`/home/${date}/${age}`)
            }}
          >
)
}
```

Then.

```
import {useLocation} from 'react-router-dom';
const DisplayPage= () => {
 const location = useLocation();

  return (
    <div>
        {location.state.date}
       {location.state.age}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: State management tools like redux are good but will require more effort.
You can try zod it has low learning cove

Comment: I have been stuck on this for 2days thanks for your help I appreciate it.